# Getting Orientation as 0 and still getting the rotated image in ImageView in android

Tags: android

I have tried most of the code on stackoverflow but none of them are working.
I am using moto x4 for uploading picture using camera. when I use back camera it gets rotated 90 degree left and when I use front camera it gets rotated 90 degree right. but in debug mode, in both case I found the orientation = 0;

```
 else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {

    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    String imagePath = saveImage(thumbnail);

    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    bmap = GetandSetBitmap.rotateBitmap(thumbnail,orientation);


    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the fact that one camera is by default in landscape and the other in reverse landscape, so orientation = 0, as the orientation is detected to be the normal one in both cases. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution that wouldn't involve manually rotating the image to cover all cases. Personally I've used a switch to cater for the cases where my photo was saved with a 90 degrees rotation:

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getPath());
                int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                Bitmap correctedBitmap;
                switch(orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        correctedBitmap = bitmap;
                        capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(correctedBitmap);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        correctedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                        capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(correctedBitmap);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        correctedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                        capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(correctedBitmap);

                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    default:
                        correctedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                        capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(correctedBitmap);
                        break;

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }
```

In your case, you would need to detect if the photo is taken from the front-facing camera or the back and adjust the values accordingly.